# problem importing credentials from python module

Tags: python

I've created a locally installed python module to keep my credentials in, away from my main application, in credentials.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os 

load_dotenv()
refresh_token =os.environ.get('refresh_token')
lwa_app_id=os.environ.get('lwa_app_id')
lwa_client_secret=os.environ.get('lwa_client_secret')
aws_secret_key=os.environ.get('aws_secret_key')
aws_access_key=os.environ.get('aws_access_key')
role_arn=os.environ.get('role_arn')

credentials = dict(
    refresh_token=refresh_token,
    lwa_app_id=lwa_app_id,
    lwa_client_secret=lwa_client_secret,
    aws_secret_key=aws_secret_key,
    aws_access_key=aws_access_key,
    role_arn=role_arn
)
print(credentials)
print()
```

When I run credentials.py, the dictionary credentials holds the right values.

However, when I try to import credentials, the following happens (in scanning.py)

```
from sellerapi_helpers.credentials import credentials
credentials
```

Output:

```
{'refresh_token': None,
 'lwa_app_id': None,
 'lwa_client_secret': None,
 'aws_secret_key': None,
 'aws_access_key': None,
 'role_arn': None}
```

When I put the .env file in the folder that scanning.py lives in, it works.

How then should I import the credentials? Do I have to just store them in the folder I am running the code? I wanted to have the credentials in one place so that when I update credentials, I don't have to change the file in multiple locations

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, make sure you include the actual output and not just your interpretations.